# Selenium xPath text concatenation

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to find an element by it's text. However I'm facing a problem with concatenating two part of the "inner" text inside an element:

```
<p>
"Copied" 
"!" 
</p>
```

If I'm trying:

1. `"//p[contains(text(),'Copied!')]"` nothing is being found
2. `"//p[contains(text(),'Copied')];` - works correctly
3. `"//p[contains(text(),'!')];` - works correctly

How it can be found?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a new line between the text parts, you can use `normalize-space()` for this. From [w3cschool](https://www.w3cschool.cn/doc_xslt_xpath/xslt_xpath-xpath-functions-normalize-space.html)

> The normalize-space function strips leading and trailing white-space
>   from a string, replaces sequences of whitespace characters by a single
>   space, and returns the resulting string.

```
//p[normalize-space('Copied!')]
```